# how to Customize Luci UI for OpenWrt?

Tags: openwrt, firmware

First of all, I'm new to OpenWrt, and all custom build firmwares.
How to compile the OpenWrt source with the Gargoyle or X-wrt UI instead of Luci?
Or with Luci but hide some functionalities from the user interface?
I couldn't find anything in the documentation to show how to do that.
In my first compilation I fallowed this steps [buildroot.exigence](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/buildroot.exigence).
My goal is to have the root user and other users have access to a limited interface with minimal configuration abilities, and make those changes to the source so I'll have a compilable version.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit LUCI from this folder:

```
usr/lib/lua/luci
...controller
...model/cbi
...view
```